# Laravel, mysql - return same row mutiple times

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

how do i return same row mutiple times? I tried using `wherein('table' , \Session::get('memory'))` aswell, but it only returned non-duplicates.
As far as i understood it would be possible with Union, but i am quite confused how to implement it.

Could anyone help me out?

**Session array:**

```
 array:5 [▼
      0 => "addon-0a65729-aak"
      1 => "visiontek-900379"
      2 => "addon-0a65729-aak"
      3 => "addon-0a65729-aak"
      4 => "addon-0a65729-aak"
    ]
```

**Query that i have so far**

```
 $memory = \DB::table('memory')->leftjoin('price', 'price.part_number' , '=', 'memory.part_number')->groupby('memory.part_number')
  ->select(
  'memory.part_number as part_number',
  \DB::raw('min(price.price) as price'),
  'price.url as url',
  'memory.slug as slug');

  foreach (\Session::get('memory') as $key) {      
     $memory = $memory->union($memory)->where('memory.slug', $key);    
  }

  $memory = $memory->get();
```

**Correct output that query would return:**

```
   ------------------------------------------------
   | part-Number| Price | URL   |       SLUG      |
   |----------------------------------------------|
   |111111     | 123.3 |http://| addon-0a65729-aak|
   |133111     | 145.3 |http://| visiontek-900379 |
   |111111     | 123.3 |http://| addon-0a65729-aak|
   |111111     | 123.3 |http://| addon-0a65729-aak| 
   |111111     | 123.3 |http://| addon-0a65729-aak|
   ------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT:**

**Memory table :**

```
memory  table
==================================================
id |   part_number   |           Slug
==================================================
1  |CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  | corsair-cmz8gx3m2a1600c9
2  |F4-3200C16D-16GVK | gskill-f4-3200c16d-16gvk
3  |F3-12800CL9D-8GBRL| gskill-f3-12800cl9d-8gbrl
4  |CMK32GX4M2A2666C16| gskill-f3-1600c9d-8gao
5  |F3-12800CL9D-8GBXL| gskill-f3-12800cl9d-8gbxl
6  |F4-2400C15D-16GVR | gskill-f4-2400c15d-16gvr
7  |F4-2666C15Q-32GRKB| gskill-f4-2666c15q-32grkb
8  |F3-1600C11D-8GNT  | gskill-f3-1600c11d-8gnt
9  |CMX4GX3M2A1333C8  | corsair-cmx4gx3m2a1333c8
10 |F4-3000C14Q-32GVK | gskill-f4-3000c14q-32gvk
```

**Price table**

```
Price table 
==================================================
id |   part_number   |   price    |    url
==================================================
1  |CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  |  122.33   | http:store_url
2  |CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  |  222.33   | http:store_url
3  |CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  |  551.00   | http:store_url
4  |CMK32GX4M2A2666C16|  1999.99  | http:store_url
5  |F3-12800CL9D-8GBXL|  222.01   | http:store_url    
6  |F4-2400C15D-16GVR |   800     | http:store_url
7  |CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  |  19.99    | http:store_url                        
8  |F3-1600C11D-8GNT  |  16.05    | http:store_url
9  |F4-3000C14Q-32GVK |  990.15   | http:store_url
==================================================
```

**Session array**

```
Session array -

array (
CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9
CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9
CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9
CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9
F3-12800CL9D-8GBXL
CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9
F4-3000C14Q-32GVK 
F3-12800CL9D-8GBXL
CMX4GX3M2A1333C8

  )
```

**Output, how it should look like**

```
Output 
==========================================================================
part number       |   Price   |     url         |         Slug
==========================================================================
CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  |  19.99    | http:store_url  | corsair-cmz8gx3m2a1600c9 //session val 0
CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  |  19.99    | http:store_url  | corsair-cmz8gx3m2a1600c9 //session val 1
CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  |  19.99    | http:store_url  | corsair-cmz8gx3m2a1600c9 //session val 2      
CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  |  19.99    | http:store_url  | corsair-cmz8gx3m2a1600c9  
F3-12800CL9D-8GBXL|  222.01   | http:store_url  | gskill-f3-12800cl9d-8gbxl  
CMZ8GX3M2A1600C9  |  19.99    | http:store_url  | corsair-cmz8gx3m2a1600c9
F4-3000C14Q-32GVK |  990.15   | http:store_url  | gskill-f4-3000c14q-32gvk
F3-12800CL9D-8GBXL|  222.01   | http:store_url  | gskill-f3-12800cl9d-8gbxl  
CMX4GX3M2A1333C8  |  NULL     |   NULL          | corsair-cmx4gx3m2a1333c8  //session val n
```

**EDIT: Found solution**
Looped through session array and query result and added values to a new array and converted the array to object.

```
$count = 0;

$newmemory = [];
foreach (\Session::get('memory') as $k => $v) {
foreach ($memory as $mem => $value) {

  if ($v == $value->slug) {
  foreach ($value as $key => $val) {

  $newmemory[$count][$key] = $val;
}

 }
  }
 $count++;
 }
$newmemory = json_decode(json_encode($newmemory));
```

Answer (score 2):

now this will be the new query using laravel 5.2 to get the expected result.

```
$final="";
    $cnt=0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $memory = DB::table("price as p")
        ->leftjoin("memory as m","m.part_number","=","p.part_number")
        ->select('m.part_number as part_number', DB::raw('min(p.price) as price'),'p.url as url', 'm.slug as slug')
        ->where("m.slug","like","%".$value."%");
        if($cnt==0)
        {
            $cnt+=1;
            $final=$memory;
        }
        else
        {
            $final=$final->unionall($memory);
        }
    }

    $final=$final->get();
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bbbrkr - i tried it already, but i need to output same row mutiple times

Comment: remove ->groupby('memory.part_number') from query

Comment: one memory can have many prices. without  ->groupby('memory.part_number') it shows only 1 row - with the lowest price of all the rows together

Comment: can you give me 10-10 record data of all three table for reference and also desired output.

Comment: added what you asked for

Answer (score -1):

In your query you will need a GroupBy('Price') if you wanna have the multiple prices

If you want the lowest one you can use the collection methods to filter or put the Min() statement in a DB::raw()

Comment: I guess i do need it it , If 1 memory can have many prices? don't i? So i would be able to find the lowest price without returning all prices.

Comment: Sorry I just misunderstand the question, if you wanna have them you still need a group by, then if you want to have it by price make the group by Price. Then if you need the lowest price just in the price use Min(Price) in your select

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my question. what i want is find rows by session value, and output them on my site. Even if in the session there are 4 equal and 1 different value,  i want echo all 5 values out like i showed in Output example above.

Comment: Your session is containing an array? Did you assign all of them in one time or they have been added time to time? Because when you use Session::put() this overwrite the value.
Maybe you will need to use Session::push('memory.slug_value', $object);

Then I don't know if this will work a Session::get('memory') or Session::get('memory.*')

Comment: Yes i am using session array and i am using session::push(arr_name, value) . And session::get('memory') returns an array.  I just need help with figuring out syntax to return same row mutiple times and as far as i understood its possible with unions.

Comment: Have you tried using collections? There is a method merge there maybe this will be useful but you need to use eloquent for that
$elquent_select = Memory::all();
$eloquent_select->merge($sesions);

Check this out [collections-merge](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-merge)

Comment: Nevermind, i guess you didn't understand the question that i am asking. Thanks anyway.